# Get current URL using webdriver.io module

Tags: javascript, node.js, mocha.js, webdriver-io

I'm trying to test that if my application correctly redirects the client after an action using the following code with `mocha.js` and `webdriver.io`.

```
it("Should redirect to correct URL.", function() {
 assert.equal(
   $("window").getAttribute("location"),      
  `http://localhost:8080/${path}`,
 );
});
```

However I get the error:

> Can't call getAttribute on element with selector "window" because
>   element wasn't found

Seems like the window object is outside `webdriver`'s selector functions scope but i can't see any other way of accessing the current URL in the docs.

Answer (score 1):

Found v4 docs with the [getUrl](http://v4.webdriver.io/api/property/getUrl.html) function.

```
it("Should redirect to correct URL.", function() {
 assert.equal(
   browser.getUrl(),      
  `http://localhost:8080/${path}`,
 );
});
```